# Not able to Initializing a new instance of the RSACng class with a specified key pair

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, cng

I want to create a new instance of RSACng class but with a specified key pair.

```
var rsa = new RSACng();
```

The above will initialize a new instance of the RSACng class with a random 2,048-bit key pair.
However we can pass an instance of `CngKey` while declaring RSACng.

```
var key = CngKey.Import(Convert.FromBase64String(_privateKey), CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob);
var rsa = new RSACng(key);
```

The above will initialize a `CngKey` object with the particular private key (the private key was obtained from a PEM file, pkcs8 format)
But this only initializes the RSACng object with private key. 
How can I initialize it with the key pair (both in PEM files) ?

Comment: The public key can be calculated from the private keys, there is no need to import it as well.

Comment: @mat how do I do that ? Considering this as a case of service to service authentication. One is provider and the one is consumer, Now the provider will be only having the public key to verify the signature that is being sent by the consumer using the private key.

Comment: Oh, you mean how can use initialise another RSACng object having only the public key?

Comment: Yes. and when I try to do that, there is no CngKeyBlobFormat that accepts the public key as in the pem file. 
I tried using the 'CngKeyBlobFormat.GenericPublicBlob' in the CngKey import method. It gives me Cryptographic exception : The parameter is incorrect.

Comment: Did you try using `CngKeyBlobFormat.GenericPublicBlob` as a parameter to CngKey.Import?

Comment: @mat as I said, it is giving me Cryptographic exception : The parameter is incorrect.


`-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCncQsf8eNxsPA/bLgnea7yAYOO
jFOu3vLtGKBCLL8H/Zjg/TwQotSUXn9XfAWkV3fsDQ0r/AZ/2o4HQeu2xvZzTHEN
fvILYp6+4dUgt/WscKyA3vzyplacQOLj2144Sc2z5yWjJ+RJORiwhvPFLqknebfG
sgnX0fjvdejro7ywcwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`


you can take the base64 encode public key and try.

Comment: Can you try to *encrypt* something using the `rsa` variable that you've just defined? If you can encrypt and decrypt then the private key already provides the public exponent as well - i.e. the encoded private key is actually the key pair. Signing and verifying would work as well, of course. And you should be able to export the public key from the RSACng as well if that is the case.

Comment: That is not a valid RSA public key. openssl can't parse it.

Comment: You generally don't want to transmit the private key to a place where you only require the public key, after all. What would be the use of the private key if that was the case?

Comment: OK, but you can still split it up into two different problems this way, e.g. looking at [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6995458/589259). First try if sign / verify works...

Comment: Actually, I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28407693/589259) together with the provided link will answer your question. Could you verify? Note that your question says nothing about parsing an exported public key using OpenSSL *at all*. Actually, my first comment or the first comment of mat should be enough to answer the question. Please update your question with your actual requirements.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I know that my question says nothing about parsing the public key using OpenSSL. 
I have tried encrypting and decrypting some bytes and it worked, it also worked with signing and verification. 
Correct me if I am wrong on this part, as I am trying to understand, the signing of data is done with the help of private key only right? and the verification of the signature is done with public key? 
I created the key pair using OpenSSL and separated them out in pem files.

Comment: @mat I created this public key with openssl only.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Also the answer that you suggested is to convert the keypair in xml format to pem format. I already have pem format. I just need to import it.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes As to your question that why do I need to send the private key to a place where I will only need public key. I have proposed a scenario in my second comment, that a consumer can send the signature along with the headers in the request to a service (provider) and the provider can verify the signature if it will have the public key.

Comment: Please clearly state your requirements in your question. I'm out.